# Wrap a function in a thread and ignore critical errors

Tags: python, multithreading

I use python version of [libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html). When I run a torrent session for a longer time with many files, it crashes with an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::lock_error'
  what():  boost::lock_error
```

so, I thought I will wrap the torrent related function into a separate thread and when it crashes, it will kill just the thread (instead of the entire app):

```
from threading import Thread

class TWrapper (Thread) :
    #  ...
    def run(self):
        try:
            run_torrent_stuff()
        except:
            # print message
            pass


t = TWrapper()
t.run()
t.join()
# check if all OK with t, if not - restart again
```

I thought that if the library crashes, the thread will die and I will `join` it in the main loop. But, when the `libtorrent` crashes, all the application dies :(

Why the error escalates outside the thread?

(`libtorrent` is an example (real life), the question is general)

Comment: 'Why the error escalates outside the thread?' - perhaps the exception is being raised on some other thread, maybe on a libtorrent internal thread/pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually if thread crashes, it leads to process crash, if you want to avoid it run libtorrent in a separate process.